# ASP.NET MVC Razor - if inside for

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to output an HTML table using razor. The table itself works, but now I'm trying to add a class called "even" to every other row in the table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.MyList.Count; i++)
        {
            var myObject = ViewBag.MyList[i];
            <tr @if (i % 2 == 0 ) { class="even" }>
                <td>myObject.Column1</td>
                <td>myObject.Column2</td>
                <td>myObject.Column3</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

There's obviously something wrong with that if-case inside the loop, but what is the correct way of writing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.MyList.Count; i++)
        {
            var myObject = ViewBag.MyList[i];
            <tr @{if (i % 2 == 0 ) { <text>class="even"</text> }}>
                <td>myObject.Column1</td>
                <td>myObject.Column2</td>
                <td>myObject.Column3</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please have a look at the razor syntax quick reference by phil haack

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

and scott guthries post about your problem

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Comment: Thanks dknaack, that works fine! And thanks for the links to. :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use CSS3 to zebra stripe your table?

```
tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
   background-color: #99ff99;
}
```